Kubernetes - basic setup, cannot connect to server
I am trying to deploy a simple API to a local Kubernetes cluster.
Here is my deployments YAML file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: container-demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: container-demo-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: container-demo-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: container-demo-app
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container-demo
          image: container-demo
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

Here is the services YAML file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: container-demo-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: container-demo-app
  ports:
  - port: 7777
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP

After I apply both, I see that the service is there:
kubectl describe service container-demo-svc
Name:              container-demo-svc
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=container-demo-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.98.60.55
IPs:               10.98.60.55
Port:              <unset>  7777/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.17:8080,10.1.0.18:8080,10.1.0.19:8080 + 3 more...
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

And the pods are there
kubectl describe pods
(excerpt:)
Name:             container-demo-app-7b8bc5c5c7-4tdnx
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             docker-desktop/<..>
Start Time:       Fri, 27 Dec 2024 16:02:45 -0600
Labels:           app=container-demo-app
                  pod-template-hash=7b8bc5c5c7
                  tier=backend
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.1.0.8
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/container-demo-app-7b8bc5c5c7
Containers:
  container-demo:
    Container ID:   docker://a0c8dee0da3351bd4de9b0ce56c762c23902d35400ef24827f5b8db4a5d784f8
    Image:          container-demo
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:fe9f22f873eb5a3014e38bd35570ff2fcb23e67596a380c80f7984334c5b9f61
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 27 Dec 2024 16:02:46 -0600
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-5hjms (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       True
  ContainersReady             True
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-5hjms:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

Now if I do
curl http://10.98.60.55:7777/api/hello

I get an error saying "could not connect to server."
However, I can run the same app in the local Docker container on port 8080 with no problem.
curl http://localhost:8080/api/hello

returns a response.
What am I doing wrong here?
